# How to post a string in a file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, post

This small code should write "a string" in the file localhost/js/user

```
<script>
 'use strict';

 (async () => {
     let response = await fetch('/js/user', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
     },
     body: "a string",
     });

     let result = await response.text();
     alert(result.message);
 })();
</script>
```

The POST returns à 200 code, but the alert is emitted and the file stays empty. What is wrong ?

Comment: If you print/debug the whole response, do you find it under some other parameter name?

Comment: console.log('response '+response) gives
*response [object Response]*

Comment: Hmm, make it easier to read with `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`. And edit your question above with the additional information

Comment: *console.log(JSON.stringify(response))* gives only *{}*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a public server mock, I was able to test your code and found that I did not need to use `.message`, but that the response body was the `response.text()`. If this does not work for you, you may need to provide more details on your `user.js` file that returns the message for this code.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
 (async () => {
     let response = await fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e81ff612f00002b002fb7ae', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
     },
     body: "a string",
     });

     let result = await response.text();
     alert(result);
 })();
```